# How to run custom setup for AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have seen this is possible in GCP and other clouds, but the "Advanced details" section in AWS EC2 doesn't seem to do anything to me.

I want to ensure I have the latest security dependencies and install custom monitoring agents.

I have tried pasting my scripts or pre-setup commands in the "User data" section. I don't see any sign of this being executed in the background. I check the history, running processes, and monitoring section.

My question is, how to do it for AWS EC2? Is the approach different compared to other clouds?

**NOTE:**
In GCP, there is both pre-config and post-config script.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
export ENV=test
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install docker -y

aws s3 cp s3://app-deployment-my-app/ec2-runner-$ENV.sh ec2-runner.sh
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo sh ec2-runner.sh
sudo chmod +x ec2-runner.sh
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "*/5 * * * * ec2-user sh /home/ec2-user/ec2-runner.sh" >> /etc/crontab'
sudo systemctl restart crond.service
```

Comment: User Data is the correct method to accomplish this in EC2. If your user data script isn't working please include it in your question. Also check the cloud-init logs on the server to see if there was an error executing the user data script. For details on how user-data/cloud-init works, see the cloud-init docs: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @MarkB I added the script I am running. I noticed that there is vertical space. Do you think it can be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud-init takes [multiple user-data formats](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html). If you want your user-data to be interpreted as a Unix script then it must begin with `#!`

**ADDITION:**

- Keep in mind that `#!` should be used with the runner of your choice, for `amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220719.0-x86_64-gp2` it was `#!/usr/bin/bash`.
- Server is available before `cloud-init` is finished, so the server is decoupled from the setup job. To ensure that cloud-init is/isn't running, try listening to cloud-init output `sudo tail -f /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Comment: I tried different variations of this: #!/usr/bin/bash, #!/bin/bash, #!

I am using AMI: `amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220719.0-x86_64-gp2`

What else may I be doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of guessing what you may be doing wrong, please look at the logs on the server to see if there are any specific error messages.

Comment: I don't get what "#!/usr/bin/bash = #!/usr/bin/sh" is trying to say in your edit to my answer. Did you mean that the `bash` shell wasn't available, so you had to change it to the `sh` shell?

Comment: I tried to say that `#!/usr/bin/bash` was the same as `#!/usr/bin/sh` but if it is more confusing than helpful, I make an edit to the answer to remove `#!/usr/bin/sh` as it slightly off the topic.

Comment: They aren't the same, they are two different Unix shells. It's unclear why you are saying they are the same.

Comment: They are the same in this particular image distribution, and /sh is symlinked to /bash.